# matrix multiplication for complex numbers in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, matrix-multiplication, complex-numbers

I am trying to multiply two complex matrices in PyTorch and it seems [the torch.matmul functions is not added yet to PyTorch library for complex numbers.](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/complex_numbers.html)

Do you have any recommendation or is there another method to multiply complex matrices in PyTorch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently `torch.matmul` is not supported for complex tensors such as `ComplexFloatTensor` but you could do something as compact as the following code:

```
def matmul_complex(t1,t2):
    return torch.view_as_complex(torch.stack((t1.real @ t2.real - t1.imag @ t2.imag, t1.real @ t2.imag + t1.imag @ t2.real),dim=2))
```

When possible avoid using for loops as these will result in much slower implementations.
Vectorization is achieved by using built-in methods as demonstrated in the code I have attached.
For example, your code takes roughly 6.1s on CPU while the vectorized version takes only 101ms (~60 times faster) for 2 random complex matrices with dimensions 1000 X 1000.

### Update:

Since PyTorch 1.7.0 (as @EduardoReis mentioned) you can do matrix multiplication between complex matrices similarly to real-valued matrices as follows:

`t1 @ t2`
(for `t1`, `t2` complex matrices).

Comment: Recently, using torch `1.8.1+cu101` I have been able to simply multiply the two tensors by `x*h`, and this is producing their complex product.

Comment: @EduardoReis You are correct. Since PyTorch 1.7.0 you can shorten the code above. But, do note that ```t1 * t2``` is pointwise multiplication between tensors ```t1``` & ```t2```. You can use ```t1 @ t2``` to obtain matrix multiplication equivalent to the ```matmul_complex```. I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this function for pytorch.matmul for complex numbers using torch.mv and it's working fine for time-being:

```
def matmul_complex(t1, t2):
  m = list(t1.size())[0]
  n = list(t2.size())[1]
  t = torch.empty((1,n), dtype=torch.cfloat)
  t_total = torch.empty((m,n), dtype=torch.cfloat)
  for i in range(0,n):
    if i == 0:
      t_total = torch.mv(t1,t2[:,i])
    else:
      t_total = torch.cat((t_total, torch.mv(t1,t2[:,i])), 0)
  t_final = torch.reshape(t_total, (m,n))
  return t_final
```

I am new to PyTorch, so please correct me if I am wrong.